# How to insert a wordpress post value into the comments title?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert the wordpress post value $offer_title into the comments box title. The title currently reads as 'Leave Your Review' but I want it to show the $offer_title value before the 'review' part like "Leave Your XYZ Review".

This is the current code for the comments section...

```
$custom_comment_field = '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="30" rows="10" aria-required="true"></textarea>';
$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
            comment_form(array(
                'comment_field'         => $custom_comment_field,
                'comment_notes_after'   => '',
                'logged_in_as'          => '',
                'comment_notes_before'  => '',
                'title_reply'           => __('Leave a Review', 'rehub_framework'),
                'cancel_reply_link'     => __('Cancel reply', 'rehub_framework'),
                'label_submit'          => __('Submit', 'rehub_framework'),
                'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(

                    'author' =>
                        '<div class="usr_re"><input id="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .'" name="author" placeholder="'.__('Name', 'rehub_framework').'"></div>',

                    'email' =>
                        '<div class="email_re"><input id="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .'" name="email" placeholder="'.__('E-mail', 'rehub_framework').'"></div>',

                    'url' =>
                        '<div class="site_re end"><input id="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) .'" name="url" placeholder="'.__('Website', 'rehub_framework').'"></div><div class="clearfix"></div>',
                )
              ),
            ));
```

Any tips would be much appreciated. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line which states:

```
'title_reply'           => __('Leave a Review', 'rehub_framework'),
```

with

```
'title_reply'           => 'Leave your '. $offer_title .' Review',
```

Comment: Perfect, worked great. Thanks for taking the time to answer this :-)